# Masking voice while in an tokbox session

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I have an application using Tokbox to create 1:1 video calls with the users. However is it possible to mask/morph the voice of a user as they speak while in a tokbox session? [Pitch Modifier](http://urtzurd.github.io/html-audio/static/)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but not using the officially supported API. You will need to intercept the getUserMedia call, make modifications to the audio track of the intercepted stream, and pass through the modified stream to opentok.js.

See https://tokbox.com/blog/camera-filters-in-opentok-for-web/ for an example on how to intercept the getUserMedia call to make modifications to the video track of the stream.

Here is a basic example of using the `mockGetUserMedia` function from the blog post to replace the audio track with a simple sine wave:

```
mockGetUserMedia((originalStream) => {
  const audioContext = new window.AudioContext();

  const destination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
  const customStream = destination.stream;
  originalStream.getVideoTracks().map(videoTrack => customStream.addTrack(videoTrack));

  const oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
  oscillator.start(audioContext.currentTime);
  oscillator.connect(destination);

  return customStream;
});
```

**Remember:** This is not an officially supported API, use at your own risk.